# Mark all chats as read on Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there a way to "Mark All as Read" for chats on Microsoft Teams? Right now I have to go and find each conversation and click on it which can be tedious if there are many of them.

[image]

I found this thread - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/how-to-mark-everything-in-chat-as-read/m-p/321752, but there wasn't a solution there.

Hopefully there is some kind of workaround, because it can be very annoying.

Comment: You're not alone https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/35338357-mark-all-as-read

Comment: Is it some design "philosophy" they are trying to shove our throats? It feels like they intentionally decided not to add this feature.

Comment: Their product manager(s) don't see it as a priority feature, which is why User Voice is there. Give it an upvote, you never know, you might push it to the top of a queue.

Comment: Another one : https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/33463540-mark-all-as-read-at-the-team-level?page=1&per_page=20

Comment: @spikey_richie I have my suspicions. I don't believe they simply forgot to add it or didn't realize people wanted it. They probably want people to be forced to go and "see" all those conversations. This is the opposite of the customer is always right.

Comment: uservoice has since moved to feedbackportal, upvote [here](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/9bf9b264-272e-ec11-b6e6-00224827bbc2) if you want this feature

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not yet possible, but there is a feature request for it which you can upvote at https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/9bf9b264-272e-ec11-b6e6-00224827bbc2 (thanks to @spinalfrontier for providing the link).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this functionality is available as filter for Chat and direct option for Activities:
[image: "Show unread" locations]